# Determining the optimal number of clusters using plots of Bayesian Information Criterion

Tags: bayesian, bic

I am having trouble interpreting the results from an Expectation Maximization clustering using `mclust` and the Iris flower data, **Using R**.

[Reproducible example](https://rpubs.com/oaxacamatt/496295)

If one were to investigate Plots 1 and 2, how do these graphics lead one to determine that the optimal number of clusters should be 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some good info that explains the BIC graphs used in R.

https://datascienceplus.com/finding-optimal-number-of-clusters/

This is what I needed initially.